# One of my questions was closed as off-topic even though it was on-topic. How can I re-open it so that it won't be deleted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-closed

I'm not sure why this question was closed as off-topic: I think it's a potentially useful question, even though I didn't put enough research effort into it before asking it. Is there anything I can do to reopen this question so that it won't be deleted in the future? (If I remember correctly, the question will be automatically deleted if it remains closed, and I think it would be counterproductive to delete this question).

I don't understand why it's necessary to delete questions that show a lack of research effort - should my question be deleted for this sole reason? I don't think my question was off-topic, even though I didn't put a lot of research effort into it). (IMO, a lack of adequate research effort should not be used as a justification for deleting a question.

The question is

[How can I find all indices of a value in a multidimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17539140/recursively-return-indices-from-nested-lists/17539216?noredirect=1#17539216)

Comment: Basic question: have you *understood* (really known how it worked, not just looked at or copied) any recursive solution? Do you understand what gnibbler means by *"Start with the terminal case"*? Once the answer to these two questions is *"yes"* you should find this problem breaks down into two parts: one of planning and one of syntax. Then you can ask about the part where you are stuck and be able to explain how it differs from just writing down the spec.

Answer (score 6):

Your question was closed because it does not demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem.

To be more specific, your question sounds a lot like "give me teh codez".

To improve your question, you can edit it to include details of what you've tried, and why that failed. Editing your question will automatically nominate it for reopening.

Also, closed questions are rarely deleted.

Comment: I wasn't asking anyone to solve the problem for me - I was only asking for advice on where to start. (Also, all off-topic closed questions (without answers) are deleted if they have a negative reputation for more than one month). Since the question is flagged as off-topic, it will almost certainly be deleted, no matter how useful the answer to the question may be.

Comment: @AndersonGreen By your explanation, your post won't be deleted, since it has an upvoted answer.

Comment: It can be deleted by anyone above a certain reputation threshold for any reason that they see fit, I think. I'm still worried that the question (and its answer) may be at risk of deletion, no matter how useful the question's answer may be.

Answer (score 5):

I was one of the hold-voters on your question. I voted as I did because the question did not show any effort. It stated your inputs and your expected results, which are the things you would provided to a paid consultant. Questions on Stack Overflow are held to higher standards.

As a reference, check out Jon Skeet's useful [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Comparing your question to that list:

- As you already indicated, you did not do your research. (item one on the list)
- You didn't explain what you have done to try to solve the problem. (item two)
- You posted some code, but didn't write a program. (item four)

I will be happy to vote to reopen the question if you wish to edit it to conform to the Stack Overflow question standards. A high-quality question is the best defense against deletion.